# "Allow Close" and a couple other options grayed out while trying to edit my custom web parts?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, permissions, sharepoint-enterprise, custom

I have a few custom web parts on my home page. When I add users to the members group (contribute permissions) they seem to be able to delete them as well. I want them to be able to interact with them but not be able to delete them.

I also tried modifying the permission slevels for contribute access but as soon as I check the "edit" option the users are able to delete the web parts again.

[image]

I looked around the net for suggestion and I found one that suggested I uncheck the "Allow Close" option by editing the web part, but it is grayed out.

Is there a way I can edit the web part code in sharepoint designer to set false?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the exact sets you need to follow :-

***Site Level Permissions >*** Unless absolutely necessary you should not give the illusive "Contribute" rights to any group of users across the entire site. The reason behind this is contribute permission level in SharePoint generally comes a very high privileges which includes deletion and modification of content across site wise. Just give users "Read" access across the entire site.

***Document Library >*** In the document library where your page resides give them "read level rights" and if needed give contribute rights to the moderator of the document library who might manage and update the webparts in the pages.

***Page >*** In the page where your webpart resides , just give read access to all users. This should be only modifiable by the document library moderator or the site collection administrators.